# Мультизагрузка изображений с проверкой

Tags: php

```
    foreach($_FILES['images']['name'] as $k=>$file) {

    $img = $_FILES['images']['type'][$k];
    $false = 0;
    if($_FILES['images']['size'][$k] > 1024*1024)
    {
        $false=$false + 1;
    }
    if($img == 'image/gif') {
        $end = ".gif";
    }
    elseif($img == 'image/png') {
        $end = ".png";
    }
    elseif($img == 'image/jpeg') {
        $end = ".jpeg";
    }

    if ($img != 'image/gif' && $img != 'image/png' && $img != 'image/jpeg') {
        $false=$false + 1;
    }


        if($false=0) {
                     ...
            }
        }

    }
```

Подскажите, почему не загружаются изображения, хотя все изображения удовлетворяют условиям? Если убрать условие if($false=0) - то будут загружаться нормально. Где тут может быть ошибка?

Comment: Как минимум последняя `}` лишняя!

-------------

Зачем `$false = $false + 1;` если можно просто `$false = 1`.

-------------

`$false = 0;` вынести за пределы цикла foreach

------------

почему не использовать `reurn true|false`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($false=0) {
             ...
    }
}
```

Видимо в самой этой строчке, которая всегда будет только `if(0)`, ведь вы присваиваете :)

Comment: Спасибо) Не заметил)

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте, может ошибка в

```
if($false=0)
```

а надо

```
if($false==0)
```

Кстати код

```
$false=$false + 1;
```

Лучше писать `$false++;`
Ваш код можно оптимизировать, последняя проверку можно убрать